# Split the role creation from the assume_role_policy with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Is it possible with Terraform to create a IAM role (with pipeline 1), then later with pipeline 2 to add assume_role_policy part?
I know I can do it with the actual polices attached to the role, but is it possible with the assume_role_policy?

My pipeline needs the role to be created in step one, but the value needed for assume_role_policy are only available in step 2.  I have alternative but that would involve a pretty large refactor.

Answer (score 1):

> then later with pipeline 2 to add assume_role_policy part?

No, you can't do that as `assume_role_policy` is a **required** argument for [aws_iam_role](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role).